# HTML code for advanced variables in Paypal button

Tags: paypal

Paypal button creation page (see the screen shot bellow) says advanced variables will appear in the button HTML code, but I cannot see any code related to that in my button HTML. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

**Solution:**

1. 'Step 2' of button factory uncheck 'saved button' - this gives you the option to decrypt the button code on the following page
2. On the Button code page make sure to click the 'Remove code protection'; view the form code

**Comments**

1. Remove the 'pn' from your variable options as it is not valid
2. [View](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/?mark=paypal%20standard%20variables) a list of valid parameters here

**Result**

input type="hidden" name="CUSTOM" value="NAME-GOES-HERE"